# MVC Limit / Redirect Role to Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, forms-authentication

I'm trying to figure out how to do this and I can't seem to arrive at an idea to try.

I have already created a filter to redirect authenticated requests, so an authenticated user cannot revisit the login page for instance.  That's all fine and dandy.

However there is one role in the system that only has access to a single area within the application, any requests to other controllers in the main area or other areas should redirect the user to this area.

I don't just want to show an unauthorised message to these users if they attempt to view anything outside of their area I would prefer to just redirect them back to their area.

what are the different ways to achieve this goal (please include pros and cons)?

**EDIT**

Just to be clear about this the reason I'm looking to do this is mop up potential edge cases where a user of a particular role enters a url from browser history or manually which coule take them to another area of the application they shouldn't be accessing.

For the *default* area of the application where the base role is `User` it is sufficient to just use the basic `AuthorizeAttribute` which just ensures requests are authorized (as most users will be granted a user role on registration.

For other areas there are specific roles which will correctly show a 401 unarthorized page to a user without the given role.

Where in this special case a certain type of user is created with a specific role and **NOT** provided with the basic `User` role but at the same time their requests will be deemed as `Authorized`.

Comment: It's typically not good practice (User Experience) to give a user a link to an area they don't have access to. Why even give them a link if they don't have access?

Comment: I don't offer these users links in the UI for areas that have no access to, but there is nothing stopping them from entering a url manually in the address bar.

Comment: Ok, so you're worried about edge-cases.  That is a good practice.

Comment: Absolutely, this is a total edge case.  Sorry I should update my question. Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close this question as it's primary opinion based (specifically as you mentioned: best). There are many ways to achieve this goal all of which of different pros/cons.  I suggest you update the question to ask *what are the different ways to achieve this goal (please include pros and cons)*.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I've updated the question with your points.

Comment: You have a rule that only have access to a controller and doesn't have access to other controllers. so you want that user with mentioned rule cant access other controllers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest and most effective way is to create a custom AuthorizationAttribute that is specific to your needs:

```
public class ThatSpecificRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    // not sure what is EXACTLY needed so here is all the stuff I
    // think someone might need
    var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string currentArea = rd.Values["area"] as string;

    if (httpContext.User != null
        && httpContext.User.Identity != null
        && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
        && httpContext.User.IsInRole("ThatSpecificRole")
        && currentController != "Home")
    {
      // alternatively you could also...
      // httpContext.Controller.TempData["ThatSpecificRoleError401"] = true;

      return false;
    }
    return true
  }

  protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction("Index", Home);
  }
}
```

Then register it globally (making sure it is the first auth attribute added):

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ThatSpecificRoleAttribute());
    }
}
```

I know someone else already mentioned something like this, but this is very specific (and multiple authorization attributes are supported by MVC, fyi).

Pros:

- You don't need to worry if someone added this to controllers or methods, it is global
- It does only what you need, everyone else (anonymous and people without the role) use the system normally.
- This will redirect them, and you could see if the TempData exists and give them a nice message letting them know they were redirected (option).

Cons:

- Every request will check this authorization.  It should be cached so the performance hit is very minimal but still exists.

Comment: This is a great answer, however what I have decided to do is remove the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` from my global filter registration and simply do it on each controller class individually.  I don't want multiple authorisations happening on each request etc.

Comment: I know this is straying off this particular topic but do you have a good link for the caching you mentioned?

Comment: [OutputCachingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Juste be careful, this could be just in ASP.NET MVC 4, but in newer version area is found in rd.DataTokens["area"].

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, and I ended up using a little hack.

When you return a HttpUnauthorized result, the user is automatically redirected to the Login-page, defined in the Web.config (in the section

However, in stead of redirecting to the login-page, I made a redirect to an different action. In this action, I check if the user is actually logged in. If so, I check what area he can view, and redirect the user to that area. If no area is found, or if the user is not logged in at all, I manually redirect to the login-page.

Hope this helps!